# How do I force all Components in a JFrame to reacquire their Background property for light/dark mode purposes?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to write an application which, for UX purposes, I want the UI to have a light mode and a dark mode... as a result, I have two color variables, and I have a getForeground() and a getBackground() that returns the appropriate colors, based on the setting of my boolean DarkMode. What I would like is to find a way to make the existing components in the window re-initialize their settings, IE: reset Background and Foreground, without having to dispose and reopen the frame. My button works to toggle the flag, and new panels opened and drawn after it's clicked are properly toggled between light and dark mode, but I can't figure out how to make the less-often-updated panels redraw themselves without loosing their current contents.

I have tried using
`frame.invalidate(); frame.validate(); frame.repaint();`

I have also tried
`frame.setVisible(false); frame.setVisible(true);`

and both those options on the JPanels as well, nothing changes the existing color palette save moving to a different panel. I feel like there must be something simple I'm missing.

```
JPanel navPanel = new JPanel();//Navigation panel for the left side of the app
    /*
     * buttons for broad concept areas of the application to be always pinned at the left
     */
    NavButton employeeButton = new NavButton("Employees", Main.getEmployeesIcon());
    NavButton settingsButton = new NavButton("Settings", Main.getSettingsIcon());
    NavButton scheduleButton = new NavButton("Schedules", Main.getScheduleIcon());
    NavButton saveButton = new NavButton("Save Data", Main.getSaveIcon());
    
    navPanel.setBackground(Main.background());
    navPanel.setOpaque(true);
    navPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
    navPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180,180));
    navPanel.add(employeeButton);
    navPanel.add(scheduleButton);
    navPanel.add(saveButton);
    navPanel.add(settingsButton);
    navPanel.add(new NavButton("Mode Change", Main.getSaveIcon()) {
        {
            addActionListener(ae ->{
                Main.toggleDarkMode();
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(mainWindow);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: A better overall solution is to make a dedicated look and feel

Comment: I'm certain this is a good suggestion. It just requires learning something I don't know so it's taking time before I can implement and confirm it works!

Comment: Look at it this way.  A look and feel delegate won't require to extend or otherwise modify pre-existing components.  The L&F could be applied to existing components without the need to change the code and any changes you make to the L&F will be reflected without changing the existing app code.  You might even just be able to get away with changing some of the default values been used by the existing L&F to get your desired results

Comment: Re. your newly added code: there's too much here that I can't access to be able to make sense of this.  The class `NavButton` is used everywhere, for example, and a bunch of static methods on Main: `Main.getEmployeesIcon()`, `Main.getSettingsIcon()`, `Main.background()`, etc.  It would be necessary for you to post a [mcve] I think.

Comment: Call setForeground(col) and setBackground(col2) on each component then call repaint() on each component.

Comment: @MadProgrammer So I've spent some time teaching myself how to use flatlaf, and somehow it doesn't want to load my customized properties file, and has managed to break everything so even the layout doesn't work anymore. I've gone from being unable to get my colors to update, to being unable to get any custom colors, elements don't work, my Panes are now layering under each other even though I'm not using an IndexedFrame, and I'm about to just huck the whole thing in the bin and say the user's getting dark mode and that's it. I appreciate the help, I'm sure if I could make it work, it'd be great

Answer (score 1):

According to Oracle it's:

**Changing the Look and Feel After Startup**

You can change the L&F with setLookAndFeel even after the program's GUI is visible. To make existing components reflect the new L&F, invoke the SwingUtilities updateComponentTreeUI method once per top-level container. Then you might wish to resize each top-level container to reflect the new sizes of its contained components. For example:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfName);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
frame.pack();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic

Comment: Thank you for the response! Thing is I'm very new and I'm not using LAF. I'm setting the background and foreground colors from variables. Maybe this is just my lack of skills forcing me to do things the hard way for now, but I really am just looking to make all the on screen Components refresh their backgrounds and foregrounds from the background and foreground methods I have available. I tried still using SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI() before, forgot to include it. It didn't work and pack wrecked my sizing.

Comment: @ShaunH The above solution won't work in your case, as you're not defining the colors within the context of the look and feel delegate, but via the components themselves, so it will have little to no effect.  It should also be noted that the fact that you "can" switch/update the look and feel this way, it was never designed to support it, so you could still end up with some weirdness. One solution would be to define your own look and feel that supported this feature, another would be to change the default colors for the current look and feel, but not all L&Fs work the same way

Comment: If the OP is totally doing their own thing, I'd need to see code.  No way to just guess how they need to update their UI.

Comment: I'll clean it up a bit and see if I can't get a relevant snippet of it that both shows what it needs to and  omits what it doesn't. Since the overall project is pretty big.

Comment: @markspace I uploaded a small section of the code but it all sort of works like you can see there where I call setBackground(Main.background(); on buttons, panels, labels, everything. Probably better handled through LAF as I was suggested by another, but still trying to figure out how to customize that!

Answer (score 0):

Switching the look & feel at run time is a fluke side effect and the API was never designed to actually support it, just beware that this could break in unexpected ways.

The "real" answer is to design for it from the start.  That is, design an actual look and feel which supports light and dark mode (or design two which can be switched between).  This allows you to define the "default" values every component should use and makes it significantly easier to switch between them.

I mean, as yourself the question, if the background color has been defined programmatically, should you be changing it?

"Another" solution would be to modify the default values used by the current look and feel.  This is some what problematic as not all look and feels use the same key sets to define there default values and don't even get me started on `JButton`.

The following is an overly simplified concept of the idea.  When I say "simplified", I'm not kidding.  There were some 719 key's been used by the `UIManager` and I didn't start looking at things like the `Border` properties.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(new JLabel("Hello"), gbc);
            add(new JTextField("Some text", 20), gbc);

            JButton flip = new JButton("Flip");
            add(flip, gbc);

            flip.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                private boolean isDark = false;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    isDark = !isDark;
                    System.out.println("IsDark " + isDark);
                    // It would be better to store the "default" values at launch,
                    // to make it easier to switch back to
                    UIManager.put("Panel.background", isDark ? new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK) : new ColorUIResource(new Color(238, 238, 238)));

                    UIManager.put("Label.foreground", isDark ? new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE) : new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK));
                    UIManager.put("Label.disabledForeground", isDark ? new ColorUIResource(new Color(192, 192, 192)) : new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK));
                    UIManager.put("Label.background", isDark ? new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK) : new ColorUIResource(new Color(238, 238, 238)));

                    UIManager.put("TextField.background", isDark ? new ColorUIResource(new Color(64, 64, 64)) : new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE));
                    UIManager.put("TextField.foreground", isDark ? new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE) : new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK));

                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(TestPane.this);

                    JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(TestPane.this);
                    if (rootPane == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    rootPane.updateUI();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You might also consider having a look around and seeing what else is available.

For example...

- [FlatLaf](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/)
- [Darklaf](https://github.com/weisJ/darklaf)
- [Darcula](https://github.com/bulenkov/Darcula)

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. And I get you, I have no doubt this is the correct way to do things. The problem is I spent 3 days trying to get a laf to work (specifically FlatDarkLaf) and if I wanted a canned LAF that breaks everything it'd be great. (seriously, how DOES a LAF make a JFrame behave like an IndexedFrame by displaying in layers? Literally all I manipulated were colors!) The thing is this has been a 36 hour complete waste of time because the LAF won't load its properties and breaks my layout frames. There's a point where I have to consider the cost/benefit analysis.

Comment: @ShaunH All I can say is you're doing "something" wrong, but I've not used any other look and feels - I tend to make use of the system laf's,  but that's me.  I've done things simular to above that make specific changes to specific properties, but not for dark mode (fonts and things)

Comment: yeah I'm not sure what I did either. I'll probably keep fussing with it a while longer but every day I keep fussing with the look & feel is another day lost in the actual development. (and if the LAF is gonna break the layout I definitely don't want to incur a bunch of tech debt by developing a lot of layout stuff and having my laf painter break it.)